# OpenCart: How to move up 'pickup from store' step before 'shipping address' step in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

Actually, my requirement is that, in OpenCart checkout process, whenever any customer choose ‘pick up from store’ option he/she should be taken directly to payment method, shouldn’t have to put in delivery details.
Since delivery details step comes before delivery method step, user is forced to fill delivery details unnecessarily. How can I do this?

Comment: needs lot to customizing in checkout/checkout

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved as many shipping options require the delivery address to be already set (and if it is not set the *pick shipping option step* redirects the user back to the *select/set shipping address step*). IMHO: the fact that even the user that wishes to use *Pick up from store* has to enter the shipping address is too minor for Your concern and for the effort it will need to be implemented (if even possible).

The only very simple solution that comes to my mind is to add a small checkbox *I will pick up my order from the store.* after checking which the shipping address won't be mandatory anymore and within the shipping options step You'd need to remove the check for shipping address in the case this checkbox was set and also **do not give the user any other option except the pick up one**. This could solve the problem quite easily with only few modifications.